# How to handle documents for view only in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

This is with the REST api. I have some documents which only need to be viewed, they have no anchor text tags on them. I found that if I gave such documents a server template id, that Docusign would use whichever document was part of the template and not the one I specified. Is the best practice to use certified viewers for such documents and not have them be signers? I noticed that if I had a server template and at least one of my documents had signing tabs, that all the other documents that I wanted to view would be viewable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, best practice here would be to use a different recipient type other than `signer`.  The certified delivery recipient should work, the carbon copy (cc) recipients should also work well in this case.

Here's what a request with a Carbon Copy recipient in routing order 2 looks like:

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign this doc",
    "status": "sent",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "test.pdf"
        }
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "signer@email.com",
                "name": "John Doe",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "xPosition": "100",
                            "yPosition": "100",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "carbonCopies": [
            {
                "email": "carbonCopy@email.com",
                "name": "Sally Doe",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you do with carbon copies as part of a composite template?